# Javascript - How to handle promises correctly with loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I am using `promises` to handle list of task:

This is a sample of code:

```
var array = ["aaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "eeee"];
var result = [];
var p = Promise.resolve({ 
  then: function(onFulfill, onReject) { 
   array.forEach(function(x){
     // http request with x and make sure this request ends before a new one if fired
     // put http resolte in array : result.push(httpRespose); 
   });
   //when done, onFulfill(result) 
}
});
p.then(
function(v) {
    console.log(v); // "fulfilled!"
  }, function(e) {
      console.log(e); // not called
});
```

I want to be able to make and http request using every element from array, then put result in an other array and when done return that new array. I also want to know if it is possible to make sure that http results are added  in the same order (it is not very important).

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Create an array of promises and resolve them with `Promise.all`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all .

Comment: You could aggregate all of the promises into an array and use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to fire when they have all completed.

Comment: `// http request with x and make sure this request ends before a new one if fired` if that's the case, you don't want promise.all

Comment: @KevinB can you please explain a bit how to handle this without promise ?

Comment: @dmx well, no, because i wouldn't suggest not using promises for http requests. I was just stating that the `all` method of `Promise` isn't suited for that purpose. It's more for parallel actions rather than actions that happen in a sequence, one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is used to wait for a number of promises to fulfill.

Each time you create a promise, push it into an array and then use

`Promise.all(myPromiseArray).then(allDoneHandler)`

Here's an example:

```js
var items = [ 500, 1000, 1500 ];
var results = [];
items.forEach((item) => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(item);
        resolve(item);
    }, item);
  });
  results.push(promise);
});
Promise.all(results).then(() => {
    console.log('done!');
});
```

Comment: Nit: `var results = items.map(item => new Promise(...));`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. That would work in my example, but for simplicity I didn't want to compress *too* much.

Comment: One-liner: Promise.all(items.map(makeAjaxRequest))).then(console.log)

Comment: Good nit, but disclaimer; no version of Internet Explorer supports arrow functions — may need to transpile.

Comment: @StephenP all of the IE versions (read: Edge) that support native Promises support arrow functions.

Comment: @xdumaine Edge ≠ IE so I don't "read: Edge", and there are polyfills for Promises, but arrow is _syntax_ that you can't introduce a function to back-fill, so you have to transpile. http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow ... if my analytics tell me I have a significant number of _Internet Explorer_ users I will have to do something to support them; Edge is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

To "run promises" in sequence (especially from an Array) you can use this pattern:

```
var donePromise = arrayOfData.reduce(function(sequence, value, index){
    return sequence.then(function(){
        //doSomethingWithValueAndReturnAPromise
    })
}, Promise.resolve());
```

but since you want the results accumulated, and not only an indicator when the job is done, we need to modufy this:

We're using `Array.map()` and `Promise.all()` to accumulate the results, and a similar approach as above to ensure the sequential execution:

```
var urls = [/*...*/];

var _sequence = Promise.resolve();
Promise.all(urls.map(function(url) {
    return _sequence = _sequence.then(function(){
        //fetch the url and return a Promise:  
        //return fetch(url).then(response => response.text())
    });
})).then(function(results){
    //console.log(results)
});
```